# Is this an efficient way to create a post stream, or is there a better way?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, while-loop

```
$FSQL = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM `connections` WHERE `uid`="'.$my_id.'" && `type`="1" ORDER by `id` DESC');
$myfriends = '`uid`="'.$my_id.'" ';
while($po = $FSQL->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $myfriends .= ' || `uid`="'.$po['cid'].'"';
}

$dsk = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE ".$myfriends." ORDER by `id` DESC LIMIT ".$limitCount);
```

I have been trying to create a nice post stream, and I finally got my code down. But it seems so inefficient if you have a large amount of connections (connections being anything from friends, pages, or events).

Could someone tell me if there is a better way to do this?

--by the way: this is working perfectly already, but I feel like i'll run into issues down the line

Answer (score 0):

`$FSQL = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM`connections`WHERE`uid`="'.$my_id.'" &&`type`="1" ORDER by`id`DESC');`

This is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should be using parameters and prepared statements. See the [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

**Worked Example**

```
$sql = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `uid`=:uid');
// Create the SQL statement, with the parameter prefixed by a ":".
$userID = "username";
// Grab the value you wish to bind to your parameter.
$sql->bindParam(':uid', $userID);
// Bind the values, using the bindParam method.
$sql->execute();
// Execute the statement with the parameters bound to the SQL query.
```

Comment: I know how to prepare values, just it wasn't necessary because $my_id is generated by PHP/SQL and a user has no ability to change that value.

Comment: Using prepared statements is the standard method for Querying an SQL database. I apologize if my answer isn't of much help, but when someone concatenates string values in an SQL query, it's a BIG red flag to most developers.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that. It's a big red flag for me too, but like I said that can't be generated by a user, so it doesn't seem like a big deal to me. I prepare most of my other statements.

Comment: Aye, that's fair enough. My point was that it's understandable why it was the first thing that jumped out at me. That is all :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use a subquery?
Something like this...

```
$dsk = $pdo->query(
    "SELECT *
       FROM `posts` 
      WHERE uid IN (
            SELECT cid
              FROM `connections` 
             WHERE `uid`="'.$my_id.'" && `type`="1"
          ) 
      ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT " . $limitCount);
```

And try not to use `*` when you don't need all fields.

Comment: subquery isn't working for me :/

Comment: Your statement would pass $my_id as a string literal; not as the variable type.